# sequelize $or with association

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a channel(model Channel) belongsTo a owner(model User) and hasMany fans(model User), I can get current user id in a request and I want to get all the channels that

**(channel.owner_id ==  current_user_id or count(channels.fans.id == current_user_id)) > 0**

that is:

**select all the channels that current user is the owner of the channel or is a fan of the channel**

How can I combine the two requirement in one $or query using sequelize of Node.js?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you please share the model codes?